# Creating a cube with css3-transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to create a "cube" effect where i can toggle between three objects and create the feeling of turning a cube.

Works fine with 2 sides, but i am stuck trying to add a third. Can someone please explain why the third site floats away?

I guess i am doing something wrong with item-3? But i just can't figure it out

```
.item-1{
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
    transform: translateZ(50px);
}

.item-2{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(-50px);
}

.item-3{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(-50px);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(-50px);
}
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/esbeka9t/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

Just change your .item-3 class like this:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateX(-180deg) translateY(200px);
transform: translateZ(-50px) rotateX(-180deg) translateY(200px)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `.items` are positioned relative to each other. Giving `.item` a `position: absolute`, a fixed `width` and changing the `translate` values just a bit on your `.item` classes should solve the issue. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/esbeka9t/2/) is a modified version of your example to illustrate this.